# Updating a controller via polling a REST call after it is initialized with Ember's connectOutlet

Tags: ember.js

Just digging into Ember JS and read through a great guide at http://trek.github.com/ regarding the use of the routers and structuring your ember app.  The framework is great and has come a long way based on some of the early tutorials.

My question is, does any one have any strong opinions/good examples/best practices for updating a instance of a controller that was initialized by the router and the `connectOutlet` method:

```
connectOutlets: function(router,context){           
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet(
        'attlist',
        'smartSensor',
        App.SmartSensor.getSensorData(context)
    );
}
```

The SmartSensor model's `getSensorData()` function calls out to a back-end REST API.  I would like to then periodically poll the server to see if the attributes of the controller have been updated and if needed update the controller.  I can think of a few ways I could force it, but nothing that seems clean.  Any ideas or am I overthinking it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would either:

a) Create a new `poller` object and give it a reference to the `smartSensorController`. The router would call `startPolling()` on the poller in your `connectOutlets` method, and call `stopPolling()` when leaving the state where it is needed (assuming it ever becomes unneeded in your app)

...or...

b) Let the `smartSensorController` take responsibility for polling. After your call to connectOutlet, do `router.get('smartSensorController').startPolling()` and a corresponding `stopPolling()` at the appropriate spot in the router.

Hope that helps!